# How do I SET to the Object's properties if I have a path array to the needed property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

```
var obj = {
  people: {
    John: {
      pets:{
        dog:{
          name:"Umbrella",
          age:12
        },
        cat:{
          name:"Kitty",
          age:5
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
var path=['people', 'John', 'pets', 'cat', 'name'];
var newName='Train';
```

How do I SET what the array wants (now it is cat's name) to the object? The array can be changed, so I can not write it by hand. I need a function to do it automatically depending on the array

Comment: I told that the array can be changed, so I don't have a possibility to write that by hands.
I need a function to do it automatically depending on the array.

Comment: I mean that you can access the object properties as an array, dude, was just a tip.

Comment: yes you need to call a function which has the below code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function like this one:

```
var prop = function (obj, chain) {
    if (obj && chain.length > 0) {
        return prop(obj[chain[0]], chain.slice(1));
    }
    return obj;
};

prop(obj, path);
```

Or even an iterative function:

```
var prop = function (obj, chain) {
    var i = 0;
    while (obj && i < chain.length) {
        obj = obj[chain[i]];
        i++;
    }
    return obj;
};

prop(obj, path);
```

**EDIT**: To set a value, you can do something like this:

```
var set = function (obj, chain, value) {
    if (obj === undefined || obj === null) return;
    var i = 0;
    while (obj[chain[i]] !== undefined && obj[chain[0]] !== null && i < chain.length - 1) {
        obj = obj[chain[i]];
        i++;
    }
    obj[chain[i]] = value;
};

set(obj, path, 'Train');
```

Comment: It worked to get the value, thanx. Now how can I SET it?

Answer (score 0):

use the below function recursively

```
foreach(var key in obj)
{
console.log('key'); //gives the key name like - people, John, Pets, dog, cat etc.,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` loop:

```
var cursor = obj;

for (var i = 0, len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
    cursor = cursor[path[i]];
}
```

Comment: Note that this may throw an exception if `John: {}`.